# Submit form and refresh product div without refresh page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, refresh

I have a form on index.php

```
<div id="right-div">
 <form name="m_srch" id="m_srch" action="'.tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT).'" method="get" > 
    ..........
 </form>
</div>
```

It is processed using

ext/form/form.php
It is included in the index.php at the top using

```
require('ext/form/form.php');
```

ext/form/form.js

---

At the end of form.php the js files are included

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/form/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/form/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/form/form.js"></script>
```

The form works in a way that when a check box is clicked--- It refreshes the whole page to list the filtered products.

I want that only the product div refreshes and not the entire page.
The products are in below div

```
<div id="left-div">......</div>
```

Please help to get this working will be deeply appreciated.....

Comment: Ajax is the thing you are looking for!

Comment: Write down your full code with ajax function call.

Comment: As you were told, you need tu use AJAX, you can take a look at Jquery for instance to find utilities.

Comment: I am a little newbie to this Ajax working could you please explain and help me on how to do it...

Comment: The form.js has  '$('#m_srch').submit();'   at end ....is this to be edited to make it work with ajax

Comment: Can anyone help me achieve this please????

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an AJAX request to your server when the form is submitted, and then send the processed data back to your JavaScript (with JSON for example). So for example, if your button had the id "#button" and you were trying to do something with an input box called "#username":

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // Initialize when document is ready
    $("#button").click(function(){ // Button is clicked
        var username = $("#username").val();
        $.ajax({ // do AJAX
            url: "form.php", // in form.php
            method: "POST", // with POST
            data: {username = username},    // in PHP, $_POST['username'] is the value of your username input box
            success: function(data) {
                // do something with the JSON
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In this example, the variable in success called data, is the part your JSON will be in sent from the server.

Now, your PHP could be something like:

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    echo json_encode($username);
?>
```

This way, it will do a request with the data "username" and that request has te value of $("#username"). Then PHP will pick that up, send it back to the AJAX request, which has it stored as JSON in the variable data, which you can use in the success function.

Good luck!

Comment: I do not have a submit button, It is automatically triggered via js when a checkbox on form is selected.....as mentioned in my above post. I want all the data to be submitted not specific elements on the form.....
Can you please explain on how can it be done...

Comment: Sorry, give me a moment, and I'll try to figure something out.

Comment: Could you please post your whole form? Or at least give me a list of what data needs to be submitted?

Comment: Okay I will just try to do that..... but cant we submit all form data ....as for now it is submitting all data on refresh

Comment: Sorry if I was a bit unclear, by posting I ment giving me a link to the code so I can try something

Comment: Sure will just try to make a pastebin... Can we serialize all data?

Comment: You could try that. Could you give me a link to your code on JSFiddle or Pastebin?

Comment: Your form with the checkbox

Comment: Are you a member on pastebin so that I could mark it private?

Comment: I think you need to give me access to it or something. My username: lja_stc

Comment: I can't figure out what the actual idea is behind what you want. Is there just 1 checkbox that needs to be checked, or is there multiple checkboxes with different values that need to be processed?

Comment: The form checkboxes are dynamically created based on products and are processed via form.php and form.js as I have I shown on my post above. As soon as a checkbox is clicked the products are loaded that are relevant to the vaalue of that checkbox. Currently the form passes all data not specific checkbox values on page refresh and hence the product are listed as per the selected checkboxes.

Comment: I guess the data: part in ajax should process the complete form data

Comment: In that case, you need to send all the checkbox data (which ones are checked) with the data option of AJAX, and then have PHP return all the relevant results. Then in the success, present them in the div.

Comment: Yes I think you understand my problem now.... Please could you help me with the code on how should I implement this...

Comment: How much checkboxes do you have, and what are their names/id's?

Comment: checkboxes are dynamic they are processed from the form in form.php and form.js functions........ can we serialize all form data rather than using the id of the checkboxes

Comment: You can, as long as you can process it with PHP. I am not 100% sure if thats possible, but you can google it.

Comment: That is the problem I am not able to find the solution to it.... Currently the form action has index.php ..... hence the index.php refreshes itself to display the result but how is this to be done for a target div... Please I know it is a little tough as I am a newbie but please your help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I tried in google previously with jquery.form.js     and edited form.js with 'function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 

    var queryString = $.param(formData); 
    $('#left-div').animate({opacity: 0.2}, 200);
    queryString='?'+queryString;
    history.replaceState({ foo: "bar" },"Google Save",document.location.pathname.toString()+queryString);    
     return true; 
}
function showResponse(responseText, statusText)  { 
    $('#left-div').animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
}' But stops working completely.not able to figure out what goes in form action='  '